# Get data of a XML with criteria

Tags: python, xml, url, beautifulsoup

i have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://windte2001.acepta.com/v01/E67EBB4910CFDCB067EB7D85FBA6E5511D0E64A9'.replace('/v01/', '/depot/')
x = urlopen(url)
new = x.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(new, "lxml-xml")
result = soup.find_all(['NmbItem','QtyItem'])
```

that brings the next result in xml

```
<NmbItem>SERV. MANEJO  DE LIQUIDOS</NmbItem>, <QtyItem>22.00</QtyItem>, <NmbItem>SERV. MANEJO DE RESPEL</NmbItem>, <QtyItem>1.00</QtyItem>]
```

All i need if NmbItem contains 'LIQUIDOS' bring me the 'QtyItem' in this case is 22

How can i do this with python in this xml?

Comment: The url is not accessible.Can you post some xml structure?

Comment: http://windte2001.acepta.com/ca4webv3/XmlView?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwindte2001.acepta.com%2Fv01%2FE67EBB4910CFDCB067EB7D85FBA6E5511D0E64A9&xsl.fulldoc=true

Comment: @KunduK http://windte2001.acepta.com/ca4webv3/XmlView?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwindte2001.acepta.com%2Fv01%2FE67EBB4910CFDCB067EB7D85FBA6E5511D0E64A9&xsl.fulldoc=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(new,'xml')
result=soup.find('NmbItem',text=re.compile("LIQUIDOS")).find_next('QtyItem').text
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
result = soup.find_all(['NmbItem'])
for item in result:
    if 'LIQUIDOS' in item.text:
        print(list(item.next_siblings)[3].text)
```

Comment: Thank u so much, can u explain me this part? list(item.next_siblings)[3].text please

Comment: ```item.next_siblings``` returns all the tags that exist on the same level as the reference tag which is 'NmbItem' in this case. I then convert it to list and take the item in index 3 which is the 'QtyItem'. ```.text``` returns the tag text.